# AJAX requests are working at home but not at my school

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cdn

I don't know if there is an error with my code or it is to do with my school internet. At home the code 'works' (by works I mean atleast displays the information from the api) but at at school I get nothing. Also here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/johnthorlby/pen/RoJKVz). Thanks for the help!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchBtn").click(function() {
    var $theData = $("#theData");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
      data: {
        action: 'opensearch',
        limit: 10,
        namespace: 0,
        search: $("#search").val(),
        format: 'json'
      },
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function processResult(apiResult) {
        var html = "";
        $.each(apiResult, function(i, apiResult) {
          var keys = Object.keys(apiResult);
          html += "<div>";
          keys.forEach(function(key) {
            html += "<strong>" + key + "</strong>: " + apiResult[key] + "<br>";
          });
          html += "</div><br>";
        });
        $theData.html(html);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(apiResult));
        console.log(html);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Open Chrome Developer Tools, tab Network, and check if your XHR requests fail.

Comment: https://imageupload.co.uk/image/BQcq That is all that was in the network tab, I don't actually see it?

Comment: Apparently jQuery can't load. Where is your jQuery? On your machine or online?

Comment: I just added it in on codepen javascript settings, also just tested it on my phone and it worked :/

Comment: It seems like your school is blocking https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com. Could you try with [another CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery)?

Comment: Ah yes, the google one worked. Brilliant, thank you! Although it didn't work on internet explorer, however it worked on chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your school is blocking https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com.

You can try another CDN, e.g. https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery.

Answer (score 0):

It will work, but you're crossing HTTP and HTTPS.

When you're running this from an HTTPS website you won't be able to post to HTTP websites. More information: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content

Change the URL in your JS code to https and it should work.

Next time, check out the developer toolbar and you should see the error message explaining pretty much what I did here;

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://codepenDOTio/johnthorlby/pen/RoJKVz' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=jQuery3100(...)ction=opensearch&limit=10&namespace=0&search=hodor&format=json&_=1481621576214'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: You could also use "//" as a protocol - this will use the protocol used by your main request.

Comment: I've done this and it still isn't working. Here is what was in the network tab on developer tools https://imageupload.co.uk/image/BQcq 
Would this suggest that its something to do with my school?

Comment: Check the console itself. It will give you a little more information. As far as I can tell now, jquery is not being loaded, hence your code won't work. Maybe the domain jQuery is on is being blocked?